# How do I optimize this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, database-indexes

```
Create table #tmptble(RuleId, SubjectId, RID, Date)

Insert into #tmptble(RuleId,SubjectId, RID, Date)
Select RuleTable.RuleId, RuleTable.SubjectId, KeyTable.RID, KeyTable.ParentId
FROM RuleTable INNER JOIN KeyTable
ON KeyTable.RID = RuleTable.RID
```

This query is very slow. I have an clustered index on RID on KeyTable, clustered index on RuleId on RuleTable, Unique non clustered index on RuleId+SubjectId on the RuleTable. (RuleTable is used in various other places)

In the above query if I introduce a where clause like

```
Insert into #tmptble(RuleId,SubjectId, RID, Date)
Select RuleTable.RuleId, RuleTable.SubjectId, KeyTable.RID, KeyTable.ParentId
FROM RuleTable INNER JOIN KeyTable
ON KeyTable.RID = RuleTable.RID
WHERE KeyTable.RID = @RID -- @RID is passed into the storedproc
```

the running time reduces by > 50%. But the problem is that I use the original table result without the `WHERE` clause in the following way

```
 WITH ResourceTree AS
(
    SELECT
    #tmptble.RuleId AS [RuleId], 
    #tmptble.SubjectId AS [SubjectRecId], 
    #tmptble.RId AS [RId], 
    #tmptble.ParentID AS [ParentID]                     
    FROM #tmptble WHERE #tmptble.SubjectId = @SubjectId
    AND #tmptble.RId = @RId 

   UNION ALL

   -- Recursive step
       -- Note that the recursive step uses the results from original #tmptable
   SELECT
   #tmptble.RuleId AS [RuleId], 
   #tmptble.SubjectId AS [SubjectId], 
   #tmptble.RId AS [RId], 
   #tmptble.ParentID AS [ParentID]                      
   FROM #tmptble INNER JOIN ResourceTree RT
   ON RT.ParentID = #tmptble.RId 
)

SELECT *
FROM ResourceTree
```

Is there a way to optimize this query? Any kind of suggestions regarding indexes or way recursion is done would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
;WITH temp AS 
(
    SELECT  
          r.RuleId
        , r.SubjectId
        , r.RID
        , k.ParentId
    FROM (
        SELECT r.*
        FROM dbo.RuleTable r
        WHERE r.RID = @RID
    ) r
    JOIN dbo.KeyTable k ON k.RID = r.RID
)
, ResourceTree AS
(
    SELECT
          t.RuleId
        , [SubjectRecId] = t.SubjectId 
        , t.RId 
        , t.ParentID                  
    FROM temp t
    WHERE t.SubjectId = @SubjectId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
          t.RuleId
        , t.SubjectId
        , t.RId
        , t.ParentID                   
    FROM temp t
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM ResourceTree r 
        WHERE r.ParentID = t.RId 
    )
)
SELECT *
FROM ResourceTree
```